# Can I change the filename of a Log4Qt configuration at runtime?

Tags: c++, qt, logging, log4cplus

I'm using [Log4qt](http://log4qt.sourceforge.net) and I followed the [official steps](http://log4qt.sourceforge.net/html/init.html) to configure a log file. I want to know if it's possible to change the configuration dynamically during runtime. Suppose the default file is "myapp.log"

```
// Set logging level for Log4Qt to TRACE
s.beginGroup("Log4Qt");
s.setValue("Debug", "TRACE");

// Configure logging to log to the file C:/myapp.log using the level TRACE
s.beginGroup("Properties");
s.setValue("log4j.appender.A1", "org.apache.log4j.FileAppender");
s.setValue("log4j.appender.A1.file", "C:/myapp.log");
s.setValue("log4j.appender.A1.layout", "org.apache.log4j.TTCCLayout");
s.setValue("log4j.appender.A1.layout.DateFormat", "ISO8601");
s.setValue("log4j.rootLogger", "TRACE, A1");

// Log first message, which initialises Log4Qt
Log4Qt::Logger::logger("MyApplication")->info("Hello World");
```

And I want to change the filename during runtime, something like this?

```
QSettings s;
s.beginGroup("Properties");
s.setValue("log4j.appender.A1.file", "C:/NewFile.log");

// Log first message, into new file
Log4Qt::Logger::logger("MyApplication")->info("Hello World");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like after you change your QSettings, and they are reflected there, you need to use:

[`Log4Qt::Properties::load()`](http://log4qt.sourceforge.net/html/class_log4_qt_1_1_properties.html#3efeb516f1ccab1bcf05dfd61c8ca208)

or

[`Log4Qt::PropertyConfigurator::configure()`](http://log4qt.sourceforge.net/html/class_log4_qt_1_1_property_configurator.html#1605298cf59cbf14c9eacd4169bd6da2)

with a reference to your QSettings variable.  If that doesn't apply the filename change, you may need to look for a way to run startup on the Log4Qt singleton.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I used Log4Qt::PropertyConfigurator::configure() because i don't have Properties class. It works correctly. Thanks so much.